# Show ViewController with Nib

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xib file:

[image]

[image]

I connect it to `TopRankViewController`

but when I push to `TopRankViewController`, there is an empty ViewController, there are no buttons here.

My code:

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    let topRankViewController = TopRankViewController(nibName: "TopRankViewController", bundle: nil)
    topRankViewController.titleLocalize(title: type.title)
    tabBarController.navigationController?.pushViewController(topRankViewController, animated: true)
}
```

I want to show those buttons which defined in my xib file.

Comment: For this you have to create an object of xib file then add this object as a subview to main view.

Comment: In xib file, `File's Owner` is `TopRankViewController`.

Comment: Give background color to view in xib and then check it works or not.

Comment: It doesn't show my chosen color. I have just tried.

Comment: Add break point in the code that you added here and check if it goes there.

Comment: Yes, It goes there. But don't know why the view is empty.

Comment: Please check you have given the correct class name to xib file.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, please check my update image.

Comment: Try change bundle to `Bundle.main`

Comment: Your code is working fine. I tried with the same and it worked for me.

Comment: have u set the view's file owner?

Comment: Yes, already set.

Answer (score 0):

I add a view inside this view and it works for me.

[image]